# Повторная установка свойств в DataTemplate при смене активной вкладки в TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе используется `TabControl` и каждая его вкладка представлена юзерконтролом с таблицей `DataGrid`.

Когда активная вкладка меняется, то свойство `ItemsSource` каждый раз устанавливается заново, что приводит к таким неприятностям как потеря предыдущего состояния полосы прокрутки и всех выделенных строк в таблице, да и просто приходится каждый раз ожидать какое-то время для подгрузки данных.

В коде при этом ничего не изменяется.

В чем проблема?

MainWindow:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <wpfTemp:MyDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

UserControl:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Не очень понял про ItemsSource, я заметил что TabControl заново перерисовывает содержимое вкладки при переходе на нее каждый раз, а не просто скрывает. А вот если вкладки зашиты в xaml, то такого нет.

Comment: @vitidev, ItemsSource у `DataGrid` устанавливается через мое свойство зависимости `itemsSource` (в разметке это видно). И если создать `PropertyChangedCallback`, то видно, что свойство переустанавливается. Но если не биндить  `ItemsSource` для `TabControl`, а в ручную создать вкладки и установить свое содержимое, то все будет работать нормально.

Comment: Ну я про следствие, а вы про причины. Так что ответ на ваш вопрос напрашивается - особенность контрола. Неприятная особенность и не единственная. Нужно для достоверности глянуть код контрола, ну не может же быть он настолько глупо написан. Но если так и есть, то нужно думать как заставить его беречь ItemsSource

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794151 - судя по всему, проблема известная и простых решений нет. Или я не то нагуглил? =)

Comment: @Monk, Огромное спасибо! То, что нужно. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: @maxwell лучше проверьте какой вариант у вас нормально и ожидаемо работает и сами отпишите =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `TabControl` старается использовать один и тот же контрол для контента всех табов. В связи с этим, конечно, визуальное состояние теряется.

Я для себя эту проблему решал так:

1. У `TabControl` убрал контент, оставил только табы.
2. Поскольку стандартный `TabControl` оставляет место, пришлось добавить отрицательный отступ снизу.
3. Под `TabControl`'ом расположил `Grid`, в котором хранились все View для контента табов, показ нужного проводился через переключение `Visibility`. Чтобы не делать это вручную, я использовал стандартный трюк с <s>`ItemsControl`'ом</s> `ListBox`'ом.

Вот полный код:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Header"
                        Margin="0,0,0,-5" x:Name="TabControlAbove">
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate/>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </Border>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TabControlAbove}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VM-классы:

```
class VM { }
class VM1 : VM
{
    public string Header { get { Debug.Print("VM1.Header.get"); return "Что-то"; } }
    public string Content { get { Debug.Print("VM1.Content.get");
                                  return "В лесу родилась ёлочка"; } }
}
class VM2 : VM
{
    public string Header { get { Debug.Print("VM2.Header.get"); return "Кто-то"; } }
    public string Content { get { Debug.Print("VM2.Content.get");
                                  return "И Гена-крокодил"; } }
}
```

`DataContext`:

```
new VM[]
{
    new VM1(),
    new VM2()
}
```

Результат:

[image: там ещё про ёжиков что-то было]

При этом геттеры срабатывают только по разу, что можно видеть в логе.

Comment: Выглядит проще и изящнее, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Проблема решена благодаря [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25907452/6641468) на английской версии SO. Спасибо @Monk.

XAML:

```
<TabControl ikriv:TabContent.IsCached="True">
    <ikriv:TabContent.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- custom content template goes here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ikriv:TabContent.Template>
</TabControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public static class TabContent
{
    public static bool GetIsCached(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCachedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsCached(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsCachedProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Controls whether tab content is cached or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>When TabContent.IsCached is true, visual state of each tab is preserved (cached), even when the tab is hidden</remarks>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCachedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCached", typeof(bool), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsCachedChanged));


    public static DataTemplate GetTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataTemplate)obj.GetValue(TemplateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTemplate(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplate value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TemplateProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used instead of TabControl.ContentTemplate for cached tabs
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Template", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public static DataTemplateSelector GetTemplateSelector(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataTemplateSelector)obj.GetValue(TemplateSelectorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTemplateSelector(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplateSelector value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TemplateSelectorProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used instead of TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector for cached tabs
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateSelectorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static TabControl GetInternalTabControl(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (TabControl)obj.GetValue(InternalTabControlProperty);
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static void SetInternalTabControl(DependencyObject obj, TabControl value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InternalTabControlProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InternalTabControl.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalTabControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InternalTabControl", typeof(TabControl), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnInternalTabControlChanged));


    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static ContentControl GetInternalCachedContent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ContentControl)obj.GetValue(InternalCachedContentProperty);
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static void SetInternalCachedContent(DependencyObject obj, ContentControl value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InternalCachedContentProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InternalCachedContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalCachedContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InternalCachedContent", typeof(ContentControl), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static object GetInternalContentManager(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(InternalContentManagerProperty);
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static void SetInternalContentManager(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InternalContentManagerProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InternalContentManager.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalContentManagerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InternalContentManager", typeof(object), typeof(TabContent), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private static void OnIsCachedChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj == null) return;

        var tabControl = obj as TabControl;
        if (tabControl == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set TabContent.IsCached on object of type " + args.NewValue.GetType().Name +
                ". Only objects of type TabControl can have TabContent.IsCached property.");
        }

        bool newValue = (bool)args.NewValue;

        if (!newValue)
        {
            if (args.OldValue != null && ((bool)args.OldValue))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Cannot change TabContent.IsCached from True to False. Turning tab caching off is not implemented");
            }

            return;
        }

        EnsureContentTemplateIsNull(tabControl);
        tabControl.ContentTemplate = CreateContentTemplate();
    }

    private static DataTemplate CreateContentTemplate()
    {
        const string xaml =
            "<DataTemplate><Border b:TabContent.InternalTabControl=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}\" /></DataTemplate>";

        var context = new ParserContext();

        context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
        context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("b", typeof(TabContent).Namespace, typeof(TabContent).Assembly.FullName);

        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("b", "b");

        var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
        return template;
    }

    private static void OnInternalTabControlChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (obj == null) return;
        var container = obj as Decorator;

        if (container == null)
        {
            var message = "Cannot set TabContent.InternalTabControl on object of type " + obj.GetType().Name +
                ". Only controls that derive from Decorator, such as Border can have a TabContent.InternalTabControl.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        if (args.NewValue == null) return;
        if (!(args.NewValue is TabControl))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Value of TabContent.InternalTabControl cannot be of type " + args.NewValue.GetType().Name + ", it must be of type TabControl");
        }

        var tabControl = (TabControl)args.NewValue;
        var contentManager = GetContentManager(tabControl, container);
        contentManager.UpdateSelectedTab();
    }

    private static ContentManager GetContentManager(TabControl tabControl, Decorator container)
    {
        var contentManager = (ContentManager)GetInternalContentManager(tabControl);
        if (contentManager != null)
        {
            /*
             * Content manager already exists for the tab control. This means that tab content template is applied 
             * again, and new instance of the Border control (container) has been created. The old container 
             * referenced by the content manager is no longer visible and needs to be replaced
             */
            contentManager.ReplaceContainer(container);
        }
        else
        {
            // create content manager for the first time
            contentManager = new ContentManager(tabControl, container);
            SetInternalContentManager(tabControl, contentManager);
        }

        return contentManager;
    }

    private static void EnsureContentTemplateIsNull(TabControl tabControl)
    {
        if (tabControl.ContentTemplate != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TabControl.ContentTemplate value is not null. If TabContent.IsCached is True, use TabContent.Template instead of ContentTemplate");
        }
    }

    public class ContentManager
    {
        TabControl _tabControl;
        Decorator _border;

        public ContentManager(TabControl tabControl, Decorator border)
        {
            _tabControl = tabControl;
            _border = border;
            _tabControl.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) => { UpdateSelectedTab(); };
        }

        public void ReplaceContainer(Decorator newBorder)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(_border, newBorder)) return;

            _border.Child = null; // detach any tab content that old border may hold
            _border = newBorder;
        }

        public void UpdateSelectedTab()
        {
            _border.Child = GetCurrentContent();
        }

        private ContentControl GetCurrentContent()
        {
            var item = _tabControl.SelectedItem;
            if (item == null) return null;

            var tabItem = _tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (tabItem == null) return null;

            var cachedContent = TabContent.GetInternalCachedContent(tabItem);
            if (cachedContent == null)
            {
                cachedContent = new ContentControl
                {
                    DataContext = item,
                    ContentTemplate = TabContent.GetTemplate(_tabControl),
                    ContentTemplateSelector = TabContent.GetTemplateSelector(_tabControl)
                };

                cachedContent.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());
                TabContent.SetInternalCachedContent(tabItem, cachedContent);
            }

            return cachedContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697788/223013) @VladD.

1. Чтобы при старте приложения первая вкладка по умолчанию была выбрана, в `MainWindow` делаем установку `Loaded += (s, e) => TabControlAbove.SelectedIndex = 0;`.
2. Также нужно обработать Ctrl+Click по содержимому вкладки, иначе будет срабатывать снятие выделения с текущего `ListBoxItem` и содержимое пропадет. Для этого вешаем на `ListBox` обработчик  `SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"`, в котором проверяем, что добавляемый элемент есть:

```
private bool cancellingTabSelectionChange;
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0 && !cancellingTabSelectionChange)
    {
        cancellingTabSelectionChange = true;
        ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
        cancellingTabSelectionChange = false;
    }
}
```